# Returning a message depending on data being deleted in TSQL using a stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm working on building a simple card game scoring program and I'm setting up a stored procedure to clear previous players and scores from my table.

I'm attempting to have the stored procedure return "Players cleared. Ready to start!" if there were records deleted from the table. Otherwise, if the table is already empty, I want it to say "Ready to start!".

My latest attempt is below. I've also tried declaring a variable and setting each of the results to that variable and returning the variable at the end.

Whenever I run the stored procedure, it only returns an empty column of "Players". I know this is from the select statement, but I'm struggling to figure out how to return the text above.

Thanks in advance!

```
CREATE PROCEDURE new_game 
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT player 
    FROM Score

    IF @@ROWCOUNT > 0
    BEGIN
        DELETE FROM dbo.Score

        PRINT 'Players cleared. Ready to start!';
    END
    ELSE 
    BEGIN 
        PRINT 'Ready to start!';
    END
END
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this.

```
    CREATE PROCEDURE new_game AS
    BEGIN
     IF EXISTS( SELECT TOP 1 player FROM Score)
     BEGIN
       DELETE FROM dbo.Score
       SELECT 'Players cleared. Ready to start!' AS Players;
     END
     ELSE 
     BEGIN 
       SELECT 'Ready to start!' AS Players;
     END
    END
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! Whenever I run the stored procedure, I get two grids returned. One says "player" and the other says "Ready to Start!". 

Now, if we could get this to only return the "Ready to start!" line, that would be great!.

Edit. The second query worked. Sorry! I didn't see it the first time! Thank you!

Comment: please get the latest solution(Second Procedure ) it gives only one response.

Comment: Yes! The second solution works perfectly! Thank you!